# How to access Heroku config variables inside Django settings

Tags: django, heroku, deployment, environment-variables

I am trying to push my code on Heroku, I have hidden my secret key using environ package but now Heroku is not able to access it since I have ignored my *.env* file using ***gitignore***, I have read about config vars in Heroku but I am having trouble understanding how do I make Django access those values

```
    import os
    import environ
    # from .secret import key
    
    env = environ.Env()
    environ.Env.read_env()
    

SECRET_KEY = env('KEY',default=env('SECRET_KEY'))
```

**updated code**
In the log, it is giving me error like this

```
warnings.warn(
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 277, in get_value
           value = self.ENVIRON[var]
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
           raise KeyError(key) from None
       KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'
       During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
           main()
         File "manage.py", line 18, in main
           execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
           utility.execute()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
           self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 244, in fetch_command
           settings.INSTALLED_APPS
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
           self._setup(name)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
           self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
           mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
         File "/tmp/build_067d1d45/food_deliveryapp/settings.py", line 22, in <module>
           SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('KEY',env('SECRET_KEY'))
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 127, in __call__
           return self.get_value(var, cast=cast, default=default, parse_default=parse_default)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 281, in get_value
           raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
       django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY environment variable
 !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
       See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every variable in `.env` create a [Config Var](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars), make sure names are UPPERCASE.

In your code you can access them via `environ` (map with all env variables):

```
my_secret = (os.environ.get("MY_SECRET", 'dev default value')
```