# Why Heroku throws 503 error , when my node app trying to connect with MongoDB Atlas?

Tags: heroku, http-status-code-503

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHUQm.png)

2021-11-20T11:44:40.554636+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/admin" host=log-store-api.herokuapp.com request_id=f5c13cb1-3e75-4767-8c41-9abd02dcfded fwd="47.11.229.75" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https

Comment: Did you enable access from outside the MongoDB network? Here is a post explaining some of the necessary steps https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/1-2-3-docker-heroku-mongodb-atlas-python-952958423bea

Comment: it's works , thanks sir . now how to hide the "connect string" , because .env file not working.

Comment: Add a Config Var on Heroku, this should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/69054819/9095551