# How to access Django secret key when git cloning from github?

Tags: python, django, git, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

So I have placed Django secret key in base.json and added that in .gitignore to prevent push and pulls to github and edited settings.py accordingly as such.

Problem is that I am trying to deploy my api to AWS ec2 and when I git clone on my Ubuntu terminal, obviously that base.json file is missing and I cannot run my code because secret key is not found. So what should I do in this case?

settings.py:

```
import os, json
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
secret_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'base.json')
with open(secret_file) as f:
secrets = json.loads(f.read())

def get_secret(setting, secrets=secrets):
    
    try:
        return secrets[setting]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = "Set the {} environment variable".format(setting)
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)

SECRET_KEY = get_secret("SECRET_KEY")

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69054762/how-to-access-heroku-config-variables-inside-django-settings) and other similar ones but they all relate to Heroku and not my case.

Comment: If you're using AWS ec2 you can create new **base.json** file there and add your secrets in it by using teminal

Comment: ohh didnt think about that! lemme try that

Comment: yep thank you for the help! I am done uploading it on AWS!

Comment: Happy to help you (;

Comment: how do I make my question resolved?

Comment: No you don't have to do any thing because your question does not contain any answer so you can delete your question but if you want keep it like this you can keep in future your question may help other.